# send multiple element to kendo multiselect from selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium2, c#

I want to sent more than one value to Kendo Multiselect element.
whenever i use the Following function

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(String.Format("$('#   {0}').data('kendoMultiSelect').value({1});", "TagName", "Value"));
```

I am able to send only one value  if I try to send another value first one is deleted

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to their live demo's HTML, that widget is is a prettily-styled list. Rather than using javascript, you should be able to click on an element found by css "div.k-widget", then click on an element with css "li.k-item" with the right text inside of it. That's the equivalent to how the user would interact with the device: click on the box, then click on the item they want judging by what the text is.

Remember: with Selenium, you're usually trying to get as close as possible to how the user will interact with the page, so you can test the user's experience.